# The connection ‘tween sine and cosine.

Tags: trigonometry

The message this animation wants to convey seems to be of particular significance, but what is it trying to explain actually?
[image]
I looked at it for hours, but I just don't get it!

Comment: Perhaps a [static image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#/media/File:Unit_circle.svg) will be more helpful.  Given a particular angle as input, when looking at a unit circle the sine of that input will be the $y$ value of where the ray for that angle intersects the circle.  Similarly, the cosine would correspond to the $x$-value.  It should be clear as well that the two are just shifts of one another due to the symmetry of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what this image intends to represent is the following:

If you were spinning around a circle in constant speed(both angular and otherwise). then your $x$ coordinate is $x(t)=c_0\cdot cos(t)$, and your y coordinate is $y(t)=c_0\cdot sin(t)$

So the image is showing that if you combine the $cos(t)$ and $sin(t)$ graph you would always obtain the curve $(cos(t)$,$sin(t))$ which is nothing more than a circle

Comment: What does $c_0$ mean?